# mouse mischief events in powerpoint

Tags: windows, coding-style

Are there any presentation start events for mouse mischief? The normal website doesn't help much with programming mouse mischief. I'm trying to do mouse emulation for kinect so I can allow mouse mischief to have a kinect being used.

Comment: I could start up an add-in of my own before mischief starts but how would i force office to do this? That seems like the best method now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the device simulation framework(dsf) and about to come out with a final product for my Kinect multipoint project. It appears that as long as a mouse device is created with dsf I do not need a presentation start event because mouse mischief recognizes the new mouse device created and allows me to include responses to mouse events. Please visit this website for updates and better details:
http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com